# SQL Server 2012 Managment Studio Basic SELECT queries

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am new to SQL Server. I have been assigned to do some simple queries to start off, then eventually move on to more complex queries.

I have spent a lot of time on this website: http://www.w3schools.com and I understand it, I think, but then when I go back to my company's database, I find myself searching from many, many, different tables with different information.

For example, a table would say `[Acct_Name]` and the query comes back with not the correct account name (s) that I need. Any advice that you think might help me? Thank you.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] to show us what you are trying and how it's getting it wrong.  Can't help you fix code we can't see, it would just be pure guesswork

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking to limit your results to specific accounts. There are many ways to go about this, so no one will be able to give you a all encompassing answer but if you are looking to just pull a single account

```
SELECT * FROM (your table name) WHERE  Acct_Name = 'the account name'
```

The * means you are selecting all columns in the table and your WHERE clause is where you set your search conditionals, like account name or by account ID. If you had a account creation date, you could get all accounts created on or before a date like this

```
SELECT * FROM (your table name) WHERE    Created < '2016-06-01 00:00:00'
```

Replace the column name 'Created' with the column that holds the date field of account creation

Learning the WHERE clause and what you can do there to limit your results will get you on a solid footing to start, from there you will want to learn JOINs and how to link tables by primary keys.

Code academy has some great tutorials https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-sql

Comment: Yes- I am looking to limit my search to specific account departments/org-Codes etc..

Comment: Thank you so much!